# How to get all possible paths between leaf nodes in a graph?

Tags: r, graph-theory, igraph

I want to obtain a list of "connected groups" in a graph.
Here is an example:

```
library(igraph)
G <- graph(c(1,2,2,3,2,5,4,5,5,6,4,7,4,8,7,8,8,9), directed=F)
plot(G)
```

I would like to get all possible paths between two leaf nodes:

```
[1] 1 2 3
[2] 1 2 5 6
[3] 1 2 5 4 8 9
[4] 1 2 5 4 7 8 9
[5] 3 2 5 6
[6] 3 2 5 4 8 9
[7] 3 2 5 4 7 8 9
[8] 6 5 4 7 8 9
[9] 6 5 4 8 9
```

I am using R. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what the exact logic here is, but you seem to want to get the paths from each of the leaf nodes to all the other leaf nodes. We can write a helper function to do that.

```
get_leaf_paths <- function(G) {
  leafs <- V(G)[degree(G)==1]
  do.call("c", lapply(1:(length(leafs)-1), function(i) {
    all_simple_paths(G,leafs[[i]], leafs[[-(1:i)]])
  }))  
}
```

Basically we find the leaf node by looking for those that are connected to only one other node, then we call all_simple_paths for each of those nodes to get connections to all the other leaf nodes. We only look for connections to others further down the list to avoid repeats. Finally we combine the results of all the shortest path calls into one object that will collect all the paths. The output would look like this

```
get_leaf_paths(G)
# [[1]]
# + 3/9 vertices, from 6d0bb8d:
# [1] 1 2 3
# [[2]]
# + 7/9 vertices, from 6d0bb8d:
# [1] 1 2 5 4 7 8 9
# [[3]]
# + 6/9 vertices, from 6d0bb8d:
# [1] 1 2 5 4 8 9
# [[4]]
# + 4/9 vertices, from 6d0bb8d:
# [1] 1 2 5 6
# [[5]]
+ 7/9 vertices, from 6d0bb8d:
# [1] 3 2 5 4 7 8 9
# [[6]]
# + 6/9 vertices, from 6d0bb8d:
# [1] 3 2 5 4 8 9
# [[7]]
# + 4/9 vertices, from 6d0bb8d:
# [1] 3 2 5 6
# [[8]]
# + 6/9 vertices, from 6d0bb8d:
# [1] 6 5 4 7 8 9
# [[9]]
# + 5/9 vertices, from 6d0bb8d:
# [1] 6 5 4 8 9
```

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question. Instead of calculating the shortest paths, I wonder how to get all possible paths between two leaf nodes.

Comment: The output here matches the output you said you wanted. Did you actually want a different output instead? I'm not sure what you want exactly.

Comment: I edited my question and used a network with more links and nodes as an example. Basically, I want to obtain all possible paths between two leaf nodes. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: OK I swapped out `all_simple_paths` for `get_shortest_paths`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe we follow the steps below:

1. Filter all leaves based on their `degree`
2. Enumerate all combinations of leaves using `combn`
3. Produce a list of `all_simple-paths` for every paired leaves

---

You can try this

```
unlist(
  combn(
    V(G)[degree(G) == 1],
    2,
    function(x) all_simple_paths(G, x[1], x[2]),
    simplify = FALSE
  ),
  recursive = FALSE
)
```

which gives

```
[[1]]
+ 3/9 vertices, from 27e9df3:
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
+ 4/9 vertices, from 27e9df3:
[1] 1 2 5 6

[[3]]
+ 7/9 vertices, from 27e9df3:
[1] 1 2 5 4 7 8 9

[[4]]
+ 6/9 vertices, from 27e9df3:
[1] 1 2 5 4 8 9

[[5]]
+ 4/9 vertices, from 27e9df3:
[1] 3 2 5 6

[[6]]
+ 7/9 vertices, from 27e9df3:
[1] 3 2 5 4 7 8 9

[[7]]
+ 6/9 vertices, from 27e9df3:
[1] 3 2 5 4 8 9

[[8]]
+ 6/9 vertices, from 27e9df3:
[1] 6 5 4 7 8 9

[[9]]
+ 5/9 vertices, from 27e9df3:
[1] 6 5 4 8 9
```